# How can i detect if the user touched the screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i want to know detect if the user touched the screen until rect is in a specific x or y position. If not stop the game here's my code:

```
func didTouchedIntime() -> Bool{
    let screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let viewHeight = screenRect.size.height
    let viewWidth = screenRect.size.width
    if rect.center.x == 0 {
        return false
    } else if rect.center.x == viewWidth {
        return false
    } else if rect.center.y == viewHeight {
        return false
    } else if rect.center.y == 0 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be most easily done with a GestureRecognizer. There are, I believe, 3 or 4 different types of GestureRecognizers. You would drag this item onto your storyboard just as you would a label or a TextField. Once this is done, you can configure the GestureRecognizer to do exactly what you want to. Finally you should connect it to an IBAction method and write all the code of pausing the game and resuming the game in there.
[Try this link for more information!](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)
Also let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: i wanted to know how to know if the user touched the screen and if not stop the game, how can i do it ?